# How to create a list of users, source ip and lastlogin on GCPW using a google spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, google-admin-sdk, google-admin-settings-api

How to create a list of users, source ip and lastlogin on GCPW using a google spreadsheets?

I'm trying to write an apps scripts to retrieve this information on last login of my domains user.

I tried those entries but the last login they retrieve is not the GCPW login.

`AdminDirectory.Users.list` (parametros)

```
var ultimoLogin = usuario.lastLoginTime
```